# How to iterate in a list of all database in a server?

Tags: powerquery, m

I just want to bring all the database table available on server with following query with generating the database name using current year function in M language.

```
let
Source = Sql.Databases(SERVER),
database2017T = Source{[Name="database2017T"]}[Data],
database2016T = Source{[Name="database2016T"]}[Data],
database2015T = Source{[Name="database2015T"]}[Data],
database2014T = Source{[Name="database2014T"]}[Data],
database2013T = Source{[Name="database2013T"]}[Data],
dbo_CBKISLEM17 = database2017T{[Schema="dbo",Item="CEKBORDRO"]}[Data],
dbo_CBKISLEM16 = database2016T{[Schema="dbo",Item="CEKBORDRO"]}[Data],
dbo_CBKISLEM15 = database2015T{[Schema="dbo",Item="CEKBORDRO"]}[Data],
dbo_CBKISLEM14 = database2014T{[Schema="dbo",Item="CEKBORDRO"]}[Data],
dbo_CBKISLEM13 = database2013T{[Schema="dbo",Item="CEKBORDRO"]}[Data],
dbo_CEKBORDRO=Table.Combine({dbo_CBKISLEM17,dbo_CBKISLEM16,dbo_CBKISLEM15,dbo_CBKISLEM14,dbo_CBKISLEM13})
```

in
    dbo_CEKBORDRO

How can I write such a query to bring all the years table ,so I don't need to update queries every year.

for xyz = 2013 to date.Year(NOW()) 
     "database" & xyz =  Source{[Name="database" & xyz &"T"]}[Data],
     "dbo_CBKISLEM" & xyz =  "database" & xyz & "T{[Schema="dbo",Item="CEKBORDRO"]}[Data],
dbo_CEKBORDRO=Table.Combine({"dbo_CBKISLEM" & xyz})

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very keen on custom-coding in the M language, but you probably don't need to for this requirement.  Just start a Query by connecting to one table in one Database.  Then delete the 2nd "Navigation" step.  Then expand the Data column to get the list of all the Tables and Views in all databases.  Then filter that list to just the tables you want (you may need to add a Custom Column to help this).  Then expand the Data column to get all the rows in each Table or View.